# Area measurement of fluorescent powder from finger contacts - batch processing

Tags: matlab, imagej

I have 120 photos like the one below showing the amount of fluorescent powder deposited onto a surface when it is touched by fingers. The photo is taken under UV light. You can see 5 finger prints and the reflection from the light source.

I'd like to know if there is an automated way of estimating the area of the fluorescent finger prints in batch mode. We have been using *image J* to manually select a particular print and estimate the area. Is it possible to automatically recognise the fingerprint in imageJ and measure it for all 5 prints on each of the 120 photos?

Note: Clearly you can see the print on the right is quite well defined but the one of the left is quite diffuse.

[image]

Comment: what do we see here? what do you expect the output to be? can you point in the image to 5 prints you are looking for (I only see three)?

Comment: Hi Shai, I have updated the question to make it more readable. I have removed reference to image intensity for the moment.

Comment: Is the setup fixed? That is, for multiple different cases, is the surface that holds the fingerprints identical and in exactly the same position, with the light from the same direction and the reflection in exactly the same spot? A fixed setup makes the problem a lot simpler.

Comment: Hi Cris, it isn't set up in that way (yet)...

Answer (score 3):

First, the data is useless without a scale, and the photos will be hard to process without a fixed set-up. I'd spend time to make a photo set up that minimizes glare and doesn't change scale, then try approaching the problem using the Threshold tool to find the prints, make selections using the resulting mask, then measuring the area. I'd then create a macro to batch process them.